# Configurable Product attibute option selection from Wishlist in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, wishlist, attribute-options

I want to Display all Configurable swatches and Attribute Dropdowns to Wishlist for Configurable Product, so the customer can select from there and directly move product to cart.
No need to go on Product page to choose options like size and color.